# customization of Esquisse icons

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm writing a small app using esquisse and I wanted to customise the icon used. I've thought about different way. The first one of course is tochange directly the icon in the package but I wanted to try something less "intrusive" I succeded in changing the style of button without touching the css, but if I try to add a js to adjust the path of were to search the icon I obtain only broken links no matter what  any idea?

there's the code

```
library(shiny)
library(datamods)
library(esquisse)
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "My navbar app",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Import Data",
    column(
      width = 4,
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = "from",
        label = "From",
        choices = c("env", "file", "copypaste", "googlesheets", "url"),
        selected = c("file", "copypaste")
      ),
      actionButton("launch_modal", "Launch modal window")
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      tags$b("Imported data:"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "name"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "data")
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Esquisse",
    esquisse_ui(
      id = "esquisse",
      header = FALSE,
      container = esquisseContainer(
        fixed = c(55, 0, 0, 0)
      ),
      controls = c("labs", "parameters", "appearance", "filters", "code"),
      insert_code = FALSE
    ),
    tags$style(
      HTML("
      .label-discrete {
        background-color: #007BC2;
        color: #FFFFFF;
       }

      .label-continuous {
        background-color: #0C4C8A;
        color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      /* box drag and drop */
      .container-drag-source, .box-dad {
        border-radius: 15px !important;
        border: dashed 2px #ccc !important;
      }"
      )
    ),
    # Inserisci il codice JavaScript direttamente nell'interfaccia
  #   tags$script(
  #     "
  # $(document).ready(function() {
  #   $('.esquisse-geom-aes img[src^=\"esquisse/geomIcon/\"]').each(function() {
  #     var currentSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  #     var newSrc = currentSrc.replace('esquisse/geomIcon/', 'geomIcon/');
  #     $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
  #   });
  # });
  # "
    # )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  # Add customIcons/www directory as a resource path
  addResourcePath("geomIcon", "geomIcon/www")
  # lauch import data modal
  observeEvent(input$launch_modal, {
    req(input$from)
    import_modal(
      id = "import-data",
      from = c("env", "file", "copypaste"),
      title = "Import data"
    )
    data_imported_r <- datamods::import_server("import-data")

    data_rv <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame())
    observeEvent(data_imported_r$data(), {
      data_rv$data <- data_imported_r$data()
      data_rv$name <- data_imported_r$name()
    })

    esquisse_server(id = "esquisse", data_rv = data_rv)
    output$name <- renderPrint({
      req(data_rv$name)
      data_rv$name
    })




    output$data <- renderPrint({
      req(data_rv$data)
      data_rv$data
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```